# anyone knows about pow alternative in ubuntu or win7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rack-pow

Lately I was configuring a rails project, other developers are in mac OS X and they were using pow [pow.cx]. but I dont have mac but I do have win7 and ubuntu, So some one plz advice me how can I configure it in win7 or in ubuntu. Can I do it using some DNS servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Linux fork for pow is there which you can use [here](https://github.com/ysbaddaden/pow)

[Hoof](https://github.com/pyromaniac/hoof/) is another alternative.

I found [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html) interesting too.

Comment: Thanks Jayram , one more question, once i run passanger start , how do I access it in browser.. ?

Comment: Go throough with the documentation http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html

Answer (score 2):

Hoof is no longer maintained, use [prax](https://github.com/ysbaddaden/prax)

Comment: Prax is no longer supported by chrome

Answer (score 1):

http://invoker.codemancers.com/ invoker needs a gem and a Procfile, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

We use Puma-Dev and are really happy with it.

https://github.com/puma/puma-dev

(Linux support exists but have only tested it on OSX)